# Set current database before calling stored procedure?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

Consider this code in C#:

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "usp_my_procedure";
```

When I execute this command, will `SQL Server` (or `MySQL` server for that matter) *know* in which database I want to run this stored procedure?

**What's the best convention here (considering both performance and security)?** Should I...

1. Explicitly specify the database name?
2. After each connection creation set the default database using the [USE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx) command?
3. Assume that the current database has been set by the connection? (E.g. `Database=mydb`)
4. Other?

Also, in SQL Server I believe it's best to explicitly specify the database owner:

```
command.CommandText = "dbo.usp_my_procedure";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use connection for one database, and you sure that it won't be changed, then you can set current database once - using USE command or just using connection string. In this case you can ommit object full names - write `dbo.table1` instead of `db_name.dbo.table1`.

If you are going to modify/refer objects from some databases, then you have a choise: execute USE command bofore the statement(s), or use full names - `db_name.dbo.table1`. You may answer the question yourself - which one is better for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
objSqlConnection.ChangeDatabase("Database");
```

OR

```
command.CommandText = "database.dbo.usp_my_procedure";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: While `ChangeDatabase` is certainly useful, this doesn't answer my question.